# Show me if the maximum value moved to other column

Tags: r

I prepared some example data so let's take a look on it:

```
> dput(example1)
structure(list(Fr1 = c(0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Fr2 = c(0.7, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), Fr3 = c(1, 0.35, 0, 0, 0, 0), Fr4 = c(0.1, 1, 0, 0, 
0.5, 0), Fr5 = c(0, 0.4, 0, 0, 1, 0), Fr6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 
0), Fr7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.7, 0, 0), Fr8 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), Fr9 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0), Fr10 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.65, 0, 0.7), Fr11 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0.2, 0, 1)), .Names = c("Fr1", "Fr2", "Fr3", "Fr4", "Fr5", 
"Fr6", "Fr7", "Fr8", "Fr9", "Fr10", "Fr11"), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", 
"Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", 
"Valiant"), class = "data.frame")

> dput(example2)
structure(list(Fr1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Fr2 = c(0.7, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), Fr3 = c(0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Fr4 = c(0.1, 0, 0, 0, 
0.5, 0), Fr5 = c(0, 0.1, 0, 0, 1, 0), Fr6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 
0), Fr7 = c(0, 0.8, 0, 0.7, 0, 0), Fr8 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
    Fr9 = c(0, 0.3, 0, 1, 0, 0), Fr10 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.65, 0, 0.7
    ), Fr11 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 1)), .Names = c("Fr1", "Fr2", 
"Fr3", "Fr4", "Fr5", "Fr6", "Fr7", "Fr8", "Fr9", "Fr10", "Fr11"
), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", 
"Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant"), class = "data.frame")
```

So, we've got 2 data frames which I would like to compare. As you see in all cells are number only from 0 to 1. Number 1 is a maximum and it has to appear atleast once in each row. For me important is in which column I can find the maximum and compare if it's in the same column in the other data frame.

Example1:

```
    Fr1 Fr2  Fr3 Fr4 Fr5 Fr6 Fr7 Fr8 Fr9 Fr10 Fr11
Mazda RX4         0.2 0.7 1.00 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0   0   0 0.00  0.0
Mazda RX4 Wag     0.0 0.0 0.35 1.0 0.4 0.0 0.0   0   0 0.00  0.0
Datsun 710        0.0 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0   0   0 0.00  0.0
Hornet 4 Drive    0.0 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.7   1   1 0.65  0.2
Hornet Sportabout 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.5 1.0 0.3 0.0   0   0 0.00  0.0
Valiant           0.0 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0   0   0 0.70  1.0
```

Example2:

```
                  Fr1 Fr2 Fr3 Fr4 Fr5 Fr6 Fr7 Fr8 Fr9 Fr10 Fr11
Mazda RX4           1 0.7 0.2 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0   0 0.0 0.00  0.0
Mazda RX4 Wag       0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.8   1 0.3 0.00  0.0
Datsun 710          0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0   0 0.0 0.00  0.0
Hornet 4 Drive      0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.7   1 1.0 0.65  0.2
Hornet Sportabout   0 0.0 0.0 0.5 1.0 0.3 0.0   0 0.0 0.00  0.0
Valiant             0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0   0 0.0 0.70  1.0
```

I made a differences only for first and second row in this example to make it easier to work but in my real data there might be difference in all of 3000 rows. As I mentioned there might be more than 1 "maximum" in each row but usually not more than 2 - number 1 appears twice.

As an output I need the name of the row and if the maximum moved (YES) or is in the same column (NO). Is it possible to do ?

To show you that two rows are different in those data sets:

Example 1:
[image: Example 1]

Example 2
[image: Example 2]

Edit:

Real data:

```
structure(list(X10 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X33.95 = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), X58.66 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.164279901), X84.42 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X110.21 = c(0.04925863, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X134.16 = c(0.4981384, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X164.69 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), X199.1 = c(0.367449159, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0), X234.35 = c(0.19587217, 0, 0, 0.96458515, 0.93848979, 
0), X257.19 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.77155521, 0, 0), X361.84 = c(0, 0, 
1, 0.76396661, 0, 0), X432.74 = c(0, 0, 0.81609991, 0.33773581, 
0, 0), X506.34 = c(0, 0, 0.81609991, 0.1390399, 0, 0), X581.46 = c(0, 
0, 0.96019504, 0.86300673, 0, 0), X651.71 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.77764596, 
0, 0), X732.59 = c(0, 0, 1, 0.45950141, 0, 0), X817.56 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0.14639304, 0, 0), X896.24 = c(0, 0.4013747, 0, 0.800272, 
0, 0), X971.77 = c(0, 0.32393615, 0, 0.74026623, 0, 0), X1038.91 = c(0, 
0.4168461, 0, 0.6808022, 0, 0), NA..1 = c(0, 0.8750537, 0, 1, 
0, 0), NA..2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), NA..3 = c(0, 0.6069765, 0, 
1, 0, 0), NA..4 = c(0, 0.53831215, 0, 0.65073089, 0, 0)), .Names = c("X10", 
"X33.95", "X58.66", "X84.42", "X110.21", "X134.16", "X164.69", 
"X199.1", "X234.35", "X257.19", "X361.84", "X432.74", "X506.34", 
"X581.46", "X651.71", "X732.59", "X817.56", "X896.24", "X971.77", 
"X1038.91", "NA..1", "NA..2", "NA..3", "NA..4"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

New edit:

I don't get it...:

```
> apply(alcr_ready,2,is.numeric)
     NA.      X10   X33.95   X58.66   X84.42  X110.21  X134.16  X164.69   X199.1  X234.35  X257.19  X361.84  X432.74 
   FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE 
 X506.34  X581.46  X651.71  X732.59  X817.56  X896.24  X971.77 X1038.91    NA..1    NA..2    NA..3    NA..4 
   FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
```

Checking again:

```
> class(alcr_ready[2,2])
[1] "numeric"
```

Edit again:

```
'data.frame':   2188 obs. of  25 variables:
 $ NA.     : Factor w/ 2890 levels "AT1G01050","AT1G01080",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 10 11 12 ...
 $ X10     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X33.95  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X58.66  : num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X84.42  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X110.21 : num  0.0493 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X134.16 : num  0.498 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X164.69 : num  1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X199.1  : num  0.367 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ X234.35 : num  0.196 0 0 0.965 0.938 ...
 $ X257.19 : num  0 0 0 0.772 0 ...
 $ X361.84 : num  0 0 1 0.764 0 ...
 $ X432.74 : num  0 0 0.816 0.338 0 ...
 $ X506.34 : num  0 0 0.816 0.139 0 ...
 $ X581.46 : num  0 0 0.96 0.863 0 ...
 $ X651.71 : num  0 0 0 0.778 0 ...
 $ X732.59 : num  0 0 1 0.46 0 ...
 $ X817.56 : num  0 0 0 0.146 0 ...
 $ X896.24 : num  0 0.401 0 0.8 0 ...
 $ X971.77 : num  0 0.324 0 0.74 0 ...
 $ X1038.91: num  0 0.417 0 0.681 0 ...
 $ NA..1   : num  0 0.875 0 1 0 ...
 $ NA..2   : num  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NA..3   : num  0 0.607 0 1 0 ...
 $ NA..4   : num  0 0.538 0 0.651 0 ...
```

Trying the code:

```
> indx1 <- max.col(alcr_ready, 'first')==max.col(tps_ready, 'first')
Warning messages:
1: In max.col(alcr_ready, "first") : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In max.col(tps_ready, "first") : NAs introduced by coercion
> indx2 <- max.col(alcr_ready, 'last')==max.col(tbl_tps, 'last')
Warning messages:
1: In max.col(alcr_ready, "last") : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In max.col(tbl_tps, "last") : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In max.col(alcr_ready, "last") == max.col(tbl_tps, "last") :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be

```
 c('NO', 'YES')[(max.col(example1, 'first')==max.col(example2, 'first'))+1]
# [1] "NO"  "NO"  "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES"
```

If `YES` denotes the `max` moved to another column, it should be the reverse

```
c('YES', 'NO')[(max.col(example1, 'first')==max.col(example2, 'first'))+1]
# [1] "YES" "YES" "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"
```

If there is a possibility of up to 2 `1`'s per row

```
 indx1 <- max.col(example1, 'first')==max.col(example2, 'first')
 indx2 <- max.col(example1, 'last')==max.col(example2, 'last')
  c('YES', 'NO')[(indx1|indx2)+1]
```

Comment: It worked fine for the example data but now I tried to use this code and I got a warning message "In max.col(alcr_ready, "first") : NAs introduced by coercion". I am curious if you have any idea why it's changing all values to `NA`. It's data.frame as well and numeric...

Comment: @ShaxiLiver Are you sure it is all numeric values in the dataset?

Comment: I checked just couple of cells from this table but it changed to `NA` all of values even those numeric. I add a small `dput` without column with names.

Comment: It looks like they are not numeric... Check my new edit. How can I change them to numeric without modification of values ? I tried by using `as.numeric` but it fails.

Comment: @ShaxiLiver Based on the dput output, it is all numeric columns `apply(alcr_ready,2,is.numeric)
     X10   X33.95   X58.66   X84.42  X110.21  X134.16  X164.69   X199.1  TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE`

Comment: How is it possible that I get all `FALSE` ?? I have no idea what's wrong because it's the same table... `apply(alcr_ready,2,is.numeric)
     NA.      X10   X33.95   X58.66   X84.42  X110.21  X134.16  X164.69   X199.1  X234.35  X257.19  X361.84  X432.74 
   FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE 
 X506.34  X581.46  X651.71  X732.59  X817.56  X896.24  X971.77 X1038.91    NA..1    NA..2    NA..3    NA..4 
   FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE`

Comment: @ShaxiLiver Looks like you included the first column which is `factor`?  Perhaps `allcr_ready[,-1]`

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to know if the maximum of each row are in the same column in the 2 datasets, you can do :

```
# find the column(s) with maximum in each dataset (in case of ex-aequo, the column numbers are separated by ";") :
max1<-apply(example1,1,function(x) paste(which(x==max(x)),collapse=";"))
max2<-apply(example2,1,function(x) paste(which(x==max(x)),collapse=";"))

# compare the 2 vectors (the 2 last lines are probably the more interesting) :
all(max1==max2)
any(max1==max2) 
sum(max1!=max2) 
which(max1 != max2)
```

**With your example :**

```
> max1
                Mazda RX4             Mazda RX4 Wag                Datsun 710            Hornet 4 Drive         Hornet Sportabout                   Valiant 
                      "3"                       "4" "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11"                     "8;9"                       "5"                      "11" 
> max2
                Mazda RX4             Mazda RX4 Wag                Datsun 710            Hornet 4 Drive         Hornet Sportabout                   Valiant 
                      "1"                       "8" "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11"                     "8;9"                       "5"                      "11" 
> which(max1!=max2)
    Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag 
            1             2 
> sum(max1!=max2)
[1] 2
```